# Theorem 7.20 in Apostol's MATHEMATICAL ANALYSIS, 2nd edition: The Comparison Theorem for Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Here is Theorem 7.20, in Chap. 7, in the book *Mathematical Analysis - A Modern Approach To Advanced Calculus* by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

> Assume that $\alpha \nearrow$ on $[a, b]$. If $f \in R(\alpha)$ and $g \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ and if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$, then we have
> $$
> \int_a^b f(x) d\alpha(x) \leq \int_a^b g(x)  d\alpha(x).
> $$

And, here is Apostol's proof:

> For every partition $P$, the corresponding Riemann-Stieltjes sums satisfy
> $$
> S(P, f, \alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^n f \left( t_k \right) \Delta \alpha_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n g \left( t_k \right) \Delta \alpha_k = S(P, g, \alpha)
> $$
> since $\alpha \nearrow$ on $[a, b]$. From this the theorem follows easily.

How to complete this argument?

My Attempt:

> Let us put
> $$
> A \colon= \int_a^b f(x) d\alpha(x), \qquad B \colon= \int_a^b g(x) d\alpha(x). \tag{0}
> $$
> If $\alpha(a) = \alpha(b)$, then we have $A = 0 = B$. So let's assume that $\alpha(a) < \alpha(b)$ and also that $A > B$.

> Then for every real number $\varepsilon$ such that
> $$
> 0 < \varepsilon \leq \frac{A-B}{2},
> $$
> there exist partitions $P_\varepsilon^\prime$ and $P_\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}$ of $[a, b]$ such that
> $$
> \big\lvert S(P, f, \alpha) - A \big\rvert < \varepsilon \tag{1}
> $$
> whenever $P$ is finer than $P_\varepsilon^\prime$ and
> $$
> \big\lvert S(P, g, \alpha) - B \big\rvert < \varepsilon \tag{2}
> $$
> whenever $P$ is finer than $P_\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}$.

> Let us put
> $$
> P_\varepsilon \colon= P_\varepsilon^\prime \cup P_\varepsilon^{\prime\prime}. 
> $$
> Then (1) and (2) above hold for any partition $P$ that is finer than $P_\varepsilon$.  Let $P$ be any such partition. Then we have
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \ \ \  S(P, g, \alpha) \\
> &< B + \varepsilon \qquad \mbox{[using (2) above]} \\ 
> &\leq B + \frac{A-B}{2} \qquad \mbox{[note that $0 < \varepsilon \leq (A-B)/2$]} \\
> &= \frac{A + B}{2} \\
> &= A - \frac{A-B}{2} \\
> &\leq A - \varepsilon \qquad \mbox{[note that $0 < \varepsilon \leq (A-B)/2$]} \\
> &< S(P, f, \alpha), \qquad \mbox{[using (1) above]} 
> \end{align}
> $$
> and hence we have
> $$
> S(P, g, \alpha) < S(P, f, \alpha).
> $$
> But this contradicts the fact that
> $$
> S(P, f, \alpha) \leq S(P, g, \alpha).
> $$
> Hence our assumption that $A> B$ is incorrect.

Is this proof correct and clear enough in each and every detail? Or, are there still some points of confusion therein?